# ts_ts for time series in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with monthly data. The data has a gap, there's months missing.

```
     DatumDok    Znesek
1  2018-01-01  4404.078
2  2018-02-01  4025.390
3  2018-03-01  4824.368
4  2018-04-01  5778.042
5  2018-05-01  7697.956
6  2018-06-01  9175.864
20 2019-08-01  7228.622
21 2019-09-01  8886.114
22 2019-10-01  8064.078
23 2019-11-01  9217.588
24 2019-12-01 13196.100
25 2020-01-01  1338.462
```

I use `train_data = ts_ts(ts_long(dataframe))` to convert dataframe to time series. ts_ts fills the missing dates with NA's as expected:

```
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
2018  4404.078  4025.390  4824.368  5778.042  7697.956  9175.864        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
2019        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  7228.622  8886.114  8064.078  9217.588 13196.100
2020  1338.462
```

But then i do the same on a dataframe with only two dates:

```
    DatumDok  Znesek
1 2017-12-01 538.752
2 2018-04-01 375.760
```

But when i use `train_data = ts_ts(ts_long(dataframe))` I get a time series of two consecutive months, instead of filling in the missing dates with NA's:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2017, 1) 
End = c(2017, 2) 
Frequency = 3 
[1] 538.752 375.760
```

So what's the problem with only having two dates?